# Configuration file in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is there a configuration file in Netezza like tnsnames.ora in Oracle which contains database names and their connect string names?

If so, what is the default location of the file?

I'm using Informatica PowerCenter to load to target Netezza table. I want to know the Database details of the connect string Informatica uses to connect with Netezza DB. In Oracle, I could have got the informatica from tns file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the dsn entry (connect string name in Informatica connection)  in the `odbc.ini` file in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is defined at the time of Netezza ODBC driver installation

Comment: Thanks for the response. odbc.ini file is NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH not in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1):

`Netezza` doesn't have an equivalent to `Oracle` TNSNames.

ODBC Connection String Example:

```
Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=myServerAddress;port=myPortNumber;
database=myDataBase;username=myUsername;password=myPassword;
```

[ODBC ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/netezza/) 
[ODBC Configuration IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/t_datacon_data_source_config.html)
[JDBC Configuration IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/r_datacon_jdbc_connection_string.html)

Comment: I'm using Informatica PowerCenter to load to target Netezza table. I want to know the Database details of the connect string Informatica uses to connect with Netezza DB. In Oracle, I could have got the informatica from tns file.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerCenter, a developer can check the connection details only if a dedicated connector is used. For ODBC, the only information available in Workflow Manager is the name of ODBC. The details can be checked in ODBC definition on the server.

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to @Marciejg: 
We have only a few odbc connections compared to powercenter connections. Each odbc points to the ‘system’ database and in the powercenter connection pointing to a specific database on that server,  we run a ‘set current_catalog PROD_EDW’ in the pre sql. That way things are mostly visible and manageable in powercenter, and the odbc only points to the server.

And slightly off topic: the pre sql has additional ‘set CLIENT_*_NAME’ statements that enters the powercenter workflow/session etc dynamically based on powercenter build in variables (they are named $PMWorkflowname and similar) 
That way we can trace back to the powercenter code immediately from a planfile, the pg.log or most interestingly, the HISTDB

Follow these links if you want to play with it:
 - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_set.html
and
http://dwhlaureate.blogspot.dk/2012/09/built-in-variables-in-informatica.html